# NSString category to calculate length combining some characters

Tags: objective-c

I need to calculate word length of string for the certain known language, which has some letter sequence, to count it as 1 letter. Say letters "ao" is one letter. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to replace each occurrence of the letter sequences by a single character and
count the length of the result:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello world";
NSMutableString *tmp = [string mutableCopy];
NSArray *sequences = @[@"ll", @"wo"];
for (NSString *seq in sequences) {
    [tmp replaceOccurrencesOfString:seq
                         withString:@"."
                            options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [tmp length])];
}
// tmp is "He.o .rld" now
NSUInteger length = [tmp length];
```

*Remark:* `length` does not count "composed characters" as a single character.
If that is an issue, you have to use `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`
with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option to count the
characters correctly. This applies for example to all "UTF-16" surrogate pairs (e.g. Emojis). It might apply to other characters such as Hangul characters as well,
I am not sure about that right now.

**ADDED**: The following method uses regular expressions and should work as well.
The advantage might be that no temporary strings are created. But one should
measure which method is really faster.

```
NSString *string = @"Hello world";

NSString *pattern = @"ll|wo|.";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:NULL];
NSUInteger length = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];


NSLog(@"length = %d", length);
```

Comment: Interesting. Having hundreds of strings to calculate length, do you think it's most optimal way? Thanks.

Comment: @Pablo: I am still thinking if I can find a better way. How many "letter sequences" do you have? Is the set of letter sequences the same for all strings to test?

Comment: Practically just one letter sequence. Yes, same for all strings to test.

Comment: Doesn't look like `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` is what I can use, since the framework doesn't know about composed characters that I need to track.

Comment: @Pablo: I have added another method to my answer. It might be faster but you should measure that. - My remark about `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` applies only to the *last step* in the first code example, i.e. replace `length = [tmp length]` by a loop counting composed characters.